# Count sequential field values based on date in seperate table using SQL

Tags: vba

I have been trying to devise an SQL query in Access 2010 to count the number of sequential field values which are based over 3 tables using fields with unique ID's

Example

Table1: Course

```
    CorID  Date
    1       01/01/2012
    2       01/03/2012
    3       01/02/2012
```

Table 2:  Delegate

```
    DelID  StaffID     CorID      Value    CounterField
    1      17263       2          99       1
    2      17263       1          99       2
    3      17263       3          99       3
    4      17263       65         4        1
    5      17263       44         5        1
    6      17263       78         5        2
```

Table 3:  Staff

```
    StaffID     Surname
    1           Test
    2           Smith
    17263       Jones
```

The CounterField increases by 1 where the Value field in Table 2 is the same as the previous Value field.  There would be a requirement to ensure that the count only uses the the order based on the course table Date field. The delegate table would also contain more DelID fields than listed and will contain different StaffID values as well.

The CounterField in the above table is an example of what I want the query to be able to do.

Is this possible?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: what’s the question again?

Comment: I want to create the counterfield (as shown above) based on the value field in the delegate table.

If the Value Field changes value as above, the counterfield needs to reset back to 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count how many rows you have in Delegate that are not duplicate regarding the `Value` field:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Delegate
WHERE CounterField = 1
```

Comment: you can also do that with a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT = 1`, but the first solution is simplier and surely faster

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answers,

I may not have made myself clear in the beginning, but I want to be able to populate the CounterField by the way I described in the original post.

To try and convert that to english:

There will be multiple courses, on different dates, with multiple delegates taken from the staff table.  I want to be able to count the Value field that is a repeat of the previous Value field when I query all 3 tables using, CourseDate (ascending) filtered by staffID in the delegate table.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try running a subquery:

> ```
> SELECT a.DelID, a.StaffID, a.CorID, a.[Value],
> (SELECT Count(*) FROM Delegate b  
> WHERE b.DelID <= a.DelID AND a.[Value]=b.[Value]) As CounterField     
> FROM Delegate a;
> ```